# Работа со строкой в C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В заданной строке изменить заданную подстроку другой подстрокой сколько бы раз она не встречалась в строке. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, r;
    char str[51], tmp[26] = {'\0'}, k;

    printf("Vvedite stroku: ");
    scanf("%s",&str);

    printf("\n");
    r=strlen(str);

    strncpy(tmp, str, r / 2);
    i = 0;
    while(str[i])
        str[i++] = str[i + r / 2];

    strcat(str, tmp);
    printf("Otvet: %s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ABIT, Поясните, что именно у вас не получается. Приведите пример вашего кода на текущий момент.

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы написали явно не соответствует поставленной задаче.

Вам нужно ввести 3 строки. Первая, та в которой ищем и меняем. Вторая - что ищем. Третья - на что меняем.

Определите, также четвертую, ту в которой будет получен результат.

Обратите внимание, что scanf("%s",str) (**правильно именно str**, а не **&str** (но можно &str[0]) (разберитесь сами *почему так*)) вводит последовательность символов до первого пробела, табуляции или подобного разделителя (подробнее в man). Это именно то, что Вы хотите ? Для ввода полной строки в Вашем случае можно использовать fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin).

Для поиска подстроки в строке удобно использовать функцию strstr(). Для решения данной задачи ее надо вызывать в цикле, каждый раз смещая начало поиска в исходной строке. Цикл завершается, естественно, когда вхождение не найдено.

С деталями (копирование), надеюсь, разберетесь сами.

Обратите внимание, что если требуется **именно заменить в исходной** строке, то это не всегда возможно, если длина результата превышает размер исходной строки.

Comment: Требую использования std::string!!!

Comment: у меня получилось ) 

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char a[100],b[1],c[1];
cout<<"BBeDiTe TEKST"<<'\n';
cin.getline(a,100);
cout<<" Symbol kotoruy nyzno zamenit "<<'\n';
cin>>b;
cout<<"\n Symbol kotorum zamenit "<<'\n';
cin>>c;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
if(a[i]==b[0])
a[i]=c[0];
}
cout<<"\n Resultat : "<<a;
_getch();
}

Comment: Молодец !  Поскольку один символ частный случай подстроки, то первый шаг сделан.

Answer (score 1):

консоль С++:

```
#include <vcl.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 #pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;
 #pragma argsused
void rcout(char *string)  //для вывода в консоли кириллицы
{
char new_string[255];
CharToOem(string,new_string);
cout<<new_string;
}
int main(void)
{
string s, s1, s2;
m:
rcout("Введите исходную строку: ");
getline(cin, s);
rcout("Введите искомое слово: ");
getline(cin, s1);
string::size_type npos,
s1_len = s1.length(),
s2_len = s2.length();
if ( s.find(s1) == std::string::npos )             //если искомое слово не найдено
{
rcout("Искомое слово не найдено!");
cout<<"\n";
goto m;
}
else                                              //если найдено
{
rcout("Введите заменяющее слово: ");
getline(cin, s2);
while(npos != string::npos)
{
npos = s.find(s1);
s.replace(npos, s1_len, s2);
npos = s.find(s1, npos + s2_len);
}
rcout("Результат: ");
cout<< s <<"\n"<< endl;
goto m;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Плюсанул. Использование стандартных контейнеров и алгоритмов - это правильно.

Comment: @gecube, а за goto почему не ругаете ?

Comment: Вообще - да, в данном случае проще было использовать `while (1) {...}` и конструкции `break`/`continue`.